# Can I set vim's relativenumber setting to be 1-indexed?

Tags: vim

I really like vim 7.3's `relativenumber` setting, but it seems to me that it should be 1-indexed. Most line-based commands operate on a number of lines that includes the current one. For example, with the below setup:

```
-1
0  def hello():<cursor>
1      """
2      Say Hello!
3      """
4      print "Hello!"
5
```

If I want to delete the whole function, I have to type `5dd` which is weird because it looks like the last line is the fourth one. Typing `4>>` doesn't indent the whole function.

The only reason to have zero indexing is for the `j` and `k` motions, but there's so many other ways to move (`w`, `}` etc.) and besides, being off by one usually isn't a big deal in motions (unless you are doing something like `d4j`).

It just seems to me that I look at the sidebar for numbers most often when I am doing line manipulation, and in those cases the default zero-index makes me do mental gymnastics. Can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's hard coded.

`d4j` and `>4j` is actually the intended use of `relativenumber`: use it the way it was meant to be used and all will be good.